# Chrome 114 segfault crash on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, google-chrome, headless, selenium

I'm using AWS EC2 instances with Amazon Linux 2 (Karoo) to run test automation with Selenium WebDriver using headless Chrome.

When upgrading to Chrome 114 (stable), ChromeDriver reports that Chrome crashes on startup.

```
======= starting test SeleniumTest.testChromeDriverOnGoogle() =======

13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.TestConfig.getEnvironment() - environment: DEV
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.TestConfig.getHeadless() - headless: true
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.TestConfig.getBrowserName() - browserName: chrome
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.TestConfig.getBrowserVersion() - browserVersion: 114
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.TestConfig.getChromeBinary() - chromeBinary: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.TestConfig.getWindowSize() - windowSize: 1200x720
13:04:42.Jul INFO  i.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.resolveDriverVersion() - Using chromedriver 114.0.5735.90 (resolved driver for Chrome 114)
13:04:42.Jul INFO  i.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.exportDriver() - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /home/runner/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.SeleniumTest.getChromeDriver() - headless: true
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.SeleniumTest.getChromeDriver() - chromeBinary: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
13:04:42.Jul INFO  org.example.SeleniumTest.getChromeDriver() - chromeOptions: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --allow-insecure-localhost, --start-maximized, --disable-gpu, --disable-dev-shm-usage], binary: /opt/google/chrome/google-c..., extensions: []}}
Jul 05, 2023 1:04:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output

======= ending test SeleniumTest.testChromeDriverOnGoogle() =======


Error:  org.mms.SeleniumTest.testChromeDriverOnGoogle -- Time elapsed: 0.225 s <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'ip-10-55-20-37.ec2.internal', ip: '10.55.20.37'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.294-220.533.amzn2.x86_64', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --allow-insecure-localhost, --start-maximized, --disable-gpu, --disable-dev-shm-usage], binary: /opt/google/chrome/google-c..., extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    
    ...
```

Here, trying from the command line:

```
sh-4.2$ cat /etc/system-release-cpe
cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2

h-4.2$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198

sh-4.2$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome -h
Segmentation fault

sh-4.2$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --headless https://google.com
[0705/125426.171854:ERROR:socket.cc(120)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer (104)
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I've tried other flags in variations, e.g.:

```
sh-4.2$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --headless=new --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage https://google.com
[0705/125611.372504:ERROR:socket.cc(120)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer (104)
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I've also tried Chrome 115 beta, which still has intermittent crashes, and sometimes fails to close -- apparently some issues interacting with Chromedriver 114.

Has anyone else seen this issue or something like it (Amazon Linux 2 is based on RH/Fedora 7) -- and found a workaround?

Barring that, is there anywhere I can get an older version of Chrome (e.g. Chrome 112)?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Amazon Linux 2023.

Comment: Has anyone noticed improvements with Chrome 116+ ?
(Note: Chrome for testing is setup to not auto-update on newer version).

I am not seeing segfaults on startup with Chrome 114 on AWS Linux 2023, but I am seeing a lot of hung chrome executables (both on Windows and Linux) -- which seem to be failures of chromedriver to successfully shutdown Chrome.